# Why am I unable start the Deluge daemon from connection manager?

Tags: deluge

I am using Deluge 1.3.5 on Ubuntu 12.04. I launch Deluge and open the `Connection Manager`, and after clicking the `Start Daemon` button I get the following message in a error message box:

`Unable to Start Daemon!
Deluge cannot find the 'deluged' executable, it is likely that you forgot to install the deluged package or it's not in your PATH.`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: "it is likely that you forgot to install the deluged package or it's not in your PATH." so.... please add in the answer to the possible suggestions.

Comment: what suggestions to which you are referring? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I think it should be fairly obvious: did you install the daemon? and is the location where the daemon resides in your PATH?

Comment: I do not know how to install the daemon. I need help doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Deluge has two 'modes' the first is the standalone application or Classic mode and the other is a split client/server model that we refer to as Thinclient mode.

I surmise that you have disabled Classic mode so Deluge is now running in Thinclient mode. If this was your intention you need to install the `deluged` package via the `Terminal`:

`sudo apt-get install deluged`

Otherwise to return to the normal standalone Deluge go to preferences and enable `Classic Mode` again.